# iOS Multiple Targets For Multiple Customers

Tags: xcode4.5

Yes i did do some research first... I got a app that need to be released for multiple customers... Currently the API web service URL for them together with other settings are stored in a Constant.h file but off course if we forget to update that file we can release a version to the wrong customer.

I found alot of references to creating multiple targets but only for free ("Lite") or paid apps: http://niharvaidya.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-create-multiple-targets-in-xcode.html

What I wanna do: Create multiple targets for each customer, each target share the same functionality, same classes, same research etc... The only thing that is different is the .plist file that is different since it have entries for different customers.

My concerns are:

- I can use the Duplicate feature but that also duplicate the .plist file and doesn't create a new one...
- If I add new resources to the project I need to check it for all the targets (customers), what if later on i add a new customer target... Do I need to go back to ALL those resources and re-add them to the new targets?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

basically I'm facing the same problem...
but take a look at this guide, using Xcode 5:

[iOS Mobile Development: Using Xcode Targets to Reuse the Code](http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/99497/iOS-Mobile-Development-Using-Xcode-Targets-to-Reuse-the-Code)

although it doesn't answer the 2 issues you mentioned, maybe you'll find it helpful using variables in the .plist files, as it's done there... for example:

```
${APP_BUNDLE_ID}
${YOUR_USER_SETTING}
```

[image]